# Can "Christ­mas" be used as an ad­jec­tive in "Christ­mas-col­ored"?

Tags: adjectives, parts-of-speech, modifiers, christmas

I was just won­der­ing whether I can write:

> Christ­mas-col­ored stock­ings

I know that *Christ­mas* can be a mod­i­fier as in *Christ­mas gift*, but can
it be used as an ad­jec­tive in *Christ­mas-col­ored*?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/87141/discussion-on-question-by-curiousstudent-can-christmas-be-used-as-an-adjective).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Christmas colors* are red and green, I believe, [throughout the West](http://www.cam.ac.uk/research/news/who-colour-coded-christmas), with white, silver, or gold often accompanying them, and in modern times other colors as well. *Christmas-colored* would be understood as such, hence you can find *[Christmas-colored flames](http://www.food.com/recipe/christmas-colored-flame-yule-logs-13694)*, and so on. But I wouldn't recommend it in general.

Most things described as *X-colored* are tinted in a *single* color—

- *[brick-coloured ribbons](http://www.smh.com.au/environment/conservation/bubble-of-methane-triggered-rig-blast-20100508-ukgj.html)*
- *[cherry-colored scarf](http://www.novelguide.com/ethan-frome/summaries/chapter1)*
- *[mud-coloured streets](http://gutenberg.net.au/ebooks02/0200441h.html)*
- *[sky-colored bra](http://www.nytimes.com/1999/02/07/style/a-night-out-with-heidi-klum-kisses-jitters-and-thongs.html)*
- *[rose-colored glasses](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/257566)*

— or in a handful of very similar colors, e.g. *[desert-coloured animals](https://books.google.com/books?id=ndaciIDpGM0C&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%22desert-coloured%22&source=bl)*. If multiple colors of a single *X* are intended, they tend to be specified— *[red, white, and blue-colored cocktails](http://spoonuniversity.com/cook/10-patriotic-desserts-you-should-make-this-4th-of-july/)*.

You can certainly invoke other imagery in narrative, referencing the appearance of a set of colors: *[kaleidoscope-coloured ornaments](http://news.bbc.co.uk/2/hi/uk_news/magazine/7121545.stm)*, *[confetti-colored lumber](http://articles.latimes.com/1997/oct/22/entertainment/ca-45242)*. In literary writing, I would take no issue with the appearance of *Christmas-colored stockings*. But in more general communication, I would prefer *stockings in Christmas colors*, and would name the specific colors in business and other communication where precision is preferable, especially in cross-cultural settings.

Comment: Can't we refer to a design palette of colors in a one word singular name, and refer to objects that use those colors as "palettename colored"? I am reminded of this: http://www.forbes.com/pictures/lmj45ljli/campbells-switches-to-the-red-and-white-label/

Comment: Since those are direct quotes, do [the rules on referencing](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) require source attribution of the author's name in plain text? Or are they so short that it doesn't matter in this case?

Comment: The color *gold* is often associated with Christmas too.

Answer (score 7):

Yes (but you do have to know what you are meaning!)

Some examples ...

*'Twas Christmas broach'd the mightiest ale;
'Twas Christmas told the merriest tale;
A **Christmas** gambol oft could cheer
The poor man's heart through half the year.*
~Walter Scott

*I wish we could put up some of the **Christmas** spirit in jars and open a jar of it every month.* ~Harlan Miller

***Christmas*** cheer.

***Christmas*** Shopping.

***Christmas*** TV special.

*Whose heart doth hold the **Christmas** glow
Hath little need of Mistletoe;
Who bears a smiling grace of mien
Need waste no time on wreaths of green;
Whose lips have words of comfort spread
Needs not the holly-berries red—
His very presence scatters wide
The spirit of the Christmastide.*
~John Kendrick Bangs (1862-1922)

***Christmas*** lists for gifts and cards.

*The **Christmas** season has come to mean the period when the public plays Santa Claus to the merchants.* ~John Andrew Holmes

*The **Christmas** bells from hill to hill
Answer each other in the mist.*
~Alfred, Lord Tennyson

*Wouldn't life be worth the living
Wouldn't dreams be coming true
If we kept the **Christmas** spirit
All the whole year through?*
~Author Unknown

***Christmas*** gift suggestions...

Comment: All your cur­rent ex­am­ples use *Christ­mas* as a noun, **ɴᴏᴛ** as an ad­jec­tive!
Zero-deriva­tion might buy you *“It does­n’t look very Christ­mas to me”* for
an ad­jec­ti­val use—but not, I sus­pect, a very well-re­ceived one: it has a
mal­odor­ous “be­cause rea­sons” smell about it in my es­ti­ma­tion. The ad­jec­tive ***Christ­massy*** has been used since 1882, but the OED still la­bels it col­lo­quial. An older
stab at de­riv­ing an ad­jec­tive yielded *Christ­masly*, as in *“as may ap­pear
by the Christ­masly han­dling thereof”* from 1608, but that one the OED la­bels
ob­so­lete.

Answer (score 0):

If you mean whether the noun Christmas can be the first element of a compound noun see Oald Christmas; especially the box "All matches". 
http://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/christmas?q=Christmas

Answer (score -1):

No. Christmas is a noun.  Your example "Christmas colored stockings" has a compound adjective "Christmas colored", made up of the noun "Christmas" and the adjective "colored" (or perhaps it's a participle).  Like any ordinary adjective, this compound adjective is equivalent to a relative clause: "which are Christmas colored".  "To be Christmas colored", in turn, means to have the colors of Christmas.

I see no reason anywhere in this derivation to make "Christmas" anything other than a noun.

Comment: It bugs me that this, the right an­swer, has been grossly un­der-ap­pre­ci­ated
by our com­mu­nity. You're spot on iden­ti­fy­ing this as hav­ing started out
life as a re­duced clause. In­deed a great many com­pound ad­jec­tives end­ing in
a “par­tici­ple-look­ing” word (Penn Tree­bank's VBN or VBG) were orig­i­nally
rel­a­tive clauses of some sort, their con­nect­ing words whit­tled away and a
shiny hy­phen added, so that they could then be con­ve­niently used as
ad­jec­tives. *Christ­mas-hat­ing grinches, cherry-col­ored cheeks, hand-col­ored orbs, hand-writ­ten let­ters*.